# iOS app name displayed on the device is wrong?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My iOS app got rejected by Apple because the name displayed on the device did not sufficiently match the name on App Store:

> Name displayed on the device: V5

I am really puzzled why this "V5" could be displayed on device.

"V5" is my project name, also the target name, in Xcode:

[image: Project V5 in Xcode]

Where in Xcode, "Display name" is set to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`, which is set to `$(TARGET_NAME)`, which is "V5"

But, I also provided localizations for `InfoPlist.strings`, in which I translated `CFBundleDisplayName`.

[image: InfoPlist.strings in Xcode]

(I am using Xcode 10.1)

I tested on real device (iPhone 7, iOS 12.2). I tested on emulators (iPhone X, iPhone XS Max, etc). I tried to change system language to different ones. But I never saw the name "V5" displayed on the device. The name displayed under the app icon is always the one I provided in `InfoPlist.strings`.

The weird thing is, I did not change my app name for years, and with exactly the same settings, I published several versions to App Store already, and never got this kind of issue.

I am wondering, if there are any recent changes from Apple that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: In your Build Settings for $(PRODUCT_NAME) do you have different values for Debug and Release? You could be seeing one value while testing but when building for release it’s using another.

Comment: @darrenallen7 In fact, $(PRODUCT_NAME) = $(TARGET_NAME) = "V5", and it's the same setting for both debug and release. But when installed on the device, the app name should be determined by the "CFBundleDisplayName" translation. I tried both debug and release build, and could never see "V5" displayed on device..

Comment: I have similar issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: @ChikabuZ yes, I resolved it. In my `Info.plist`, originally I had: `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key><string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>`. I replaced `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` by the English name of my app, so that it would not be resolved to the internal codename V5. It actually makes no difference to users, but I think Apple reviewers will use the app in an i18n-neutral environment, so they are the only guys who can see this internal codename displayed as app name.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set the project name on the itunes.connect website

Comment: Not correct. The app name on App Store Connect is only the one displayed on the App Store. The device name is set in Xcode.